# Check that a *type* of file exists in Python

Tags: python

I realize this looks similar to other questions about checking if a file exists, but it is different. I'm trying to figure out how to check that a **type** of file exists and exit if it doesn't. The code I tried originally is this:

```
filenames = os.listdir(os.curdir)

for filename in filenames:

   if os.path.isfile(filename) and filename.endswith('.fna'):
        ##do stuff
```

This works to 'do stuff' to the file that ends in .fna, but I need it to check and make sure the .fna file is there and exit the program entirely if not.

I tried this:

```
try:

    if os.path.isfile(filename) and filename.endswith('.fna'):
        ## Do stuff 
except: 

    sys.stderr.write (‘No database file found. Exiting program. /n’)
    sys.exit(-1)
```

But that didn't work, it just skips the whole function if the .fna file isn't there, without printing the error.

Comment: And you have a typo in your singly-quotation mark

Comment: And a weird non-escape sequence `/n`.

Answer (score 12):

The [`for` statement in Python](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) has a little-known `else` clause:

```
for filename in filenames:
    if os.path.isfile(filename) and filename.endswith(".fna"):
        # do stuff
        break
else:
    sys.stderr.write ('No database file found. Exiting program. \n')
    sys.exit(-1)
```

The `else` clause is run *only* if the `for` statement runs through its whole enumeration without executing the `break` inside the loop.

Answer (score 8):

Look at the [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module:

```
import glob
import os
import sys

databases = filter(os.path.isfile, glob.glob('./*.fna'))

if not databases:
    sys.stderr.write("No database found.\n\n")
    exit(1)

for database in databases:
    do_something_with(database)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
filenames = os.listdir(os.curdir)
found = False
for filename in filenames:
    if os.path.isfile(filename) and filename.endswith('.fna'):
        found = True
if not found:
    sys.stderr.write ('No database file found. Exiting program. \n')
    sys.exit(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using exceptions, do not test to see if the file exists. That's why you're using exceptions to start with.

```
try:
    # No if statement doing the check
    # Start doing stuff assuming abc.fna exists
except:
    # Uh oh! Something went bad.
    # Display error messages, clean up, carry on
```

To clarify, consider the code snippet:

```
try:
    with open('hi.txt') as f:
        print f.readlines()
except:
    print 'There is no hi.txt!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `try`/`except` block didn't work because `os.path.isfile` does not throw an exception if it fails; it merely returns `False`.

`else` clauses for `for` loops are weird and non-intuitive. Using `break` to signify that the loop was successful rather than legitimately breaking it is just weird, and contrary to Python's philosophy.

Here's a nice, Pythonic way of doing what you want:

```
want = lambda f: os.path.isfile(f) and f.endswith(".fna")
valid_files = [f for f in os.listdir(os.curdir) if want(f)]
if len(valid_files) == 0:
    print >>sys.stderr, "failed to find .fna files!"
    sys.exit(1)
for filename in valid_files:
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out os.path.splitext(path) function which says:

> Split the pathname path into a pair (root, ext) such that root + ext == path, and ext is empty or begins with a period and contains at most one period. Leading periods on the basename are ignored; splitext('.cshrc') returns ('.cshrc', '').

Here's an example:

```
>>> os.path.splitext("./01The News from Lake Wobegon/AlbumArtSmall.jpg")
('./01The News from Lake Wobegon/AlbumArtSmall', '.jpg')
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have a very similar code photo as you but mine is a code like is there an error or not. maybe you can find something useful

```
for belge in tarama: 
    try:
        
        
        if belge.name.endswith('.docx') or belge.name.endswith('.doc'):
            Document(belge)
        
        elif belge.name.endswith('.pptx'):
            Presentation(belge)
            
        elif belge.name.endswith(".xlsx"):
            pd.read_excel(belge)
        
        elif belge.name.endswith(".pdf"):
            pdfpath=os.path.abspath(belge)
            PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdfpath)
            
        elif belge.name.endswith(".jpg") or belge.name.endswith(".jpeg"):
            jpgpath=os.path.abspath(belge)
            matplotlib.image.imread(jpgpath)
            
        else:
            yenipath=os.path.abspath(belge)
            tarama=os.scandir(yenipath)
        
            func(tarama)
            
    except :
        print ("Dosya açılmıyor !",belge.name)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).